# Listbox with multiple columns of the same contents

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to make multiple columns in a `ListBox` control using WinForms? The columns should have one `DataSource`. Example:

```
1    5
2    6
3    7
4    8
```

I want to assign, for example, a list of `int` to a `ListBox`, but I want to have multiple columns.
I mean, I want to have one column that wraps. I hope I explained it fine...

Comment: A List*View* supports multiple columns (in report view)

Comment: For more than one column I'd suggest using a `DataGridView` instead of a `ListBox`.

Comment: but can I have one DataSource in DataGridView?

Comment: Yes, just use `dataGridView1.DataSource = yourSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is a built-in feature that you can simply enable with the designer.  Set the MultiColumns property to True and the ColumWidth property to a value larger than 0.  That's all, the horizontal scrollbar automatically appears when the content doesn't fit the box.

Comment: This is it. I thought it should be that easy, but didn't know where to find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a `DataGridView` instead of a `ListBox` to display more than one column. I'll give you an example.

Using a `DataTable` as `DataSource`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "5");
dt.Rows.Add("2", "6");
dt.Rows.Add("3", "7");
dt.Rows.Add("4", "8");

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Using a generic list as `DataSource`:

```
List<YourClass> list = new List<YourClass>();

YourClass yc = new YourClass();
yc.Column1 = "1";
yc.Column2 = "5";

list.Add(yc);
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;

public class YourClass
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```